# GPG.exe return error code 2

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

`gpg.exe` return a error code `2` for a particular machine. The code is working fine in other machines. Is this `gpg.exe` is machine dependent or do we need any separate settings for this in the machine?

my command is like this

```
gpg.exe --batch --output "I:\dataload\W2\QA2\PPP\S451.pgp" --recipient "***.*****@****.**.com" --encrypt "I:\dataload\W2\QA2\PPP\S451"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at dependencies and make sure python and all relevant packages are installed on that machine. Your machine can't find a specified file so check to see that all dependencies are met. Maybe post a little more about the error.

Comment: actually do you know what are the dependencies which are essentials to work gpg.exe?

Comment: I havent really worked with it before but this site has some stuff: http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2068  and pycrypto may have what you need